# Google Login "error": "popup_closed_by_user"

Tags: google-chrome, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client

Im using google login in my app and it works perfectly fine but if you click the button and then decide to close it or cancel the popup to cancel the login, I get a pop up that says ' "error": "popup_closed_by_user" ' and this behavior is in all browsers.

How can I prevent this popup from happening everytime the popup is closed?

Comment: Related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801021/angular-social-logging-error-with-google-popup-closed-by-user

I've the same error. 
Did you manage to make progress on that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback function to handle the error popup. In my case, i was using  [@abacritt/angularx-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login) and handled the error popup using the below code:

```
this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID)
.then(() => {
  //success case
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error); //the behaviour of error popup can be handled here
});
```